# numpy coercion problem for left-sided binary operator

Tags: python, numpy, coercion

I am implementing an array-like object that should be interoperable with standard numpy arrays. I just hit an annoying problem that narrows down to the following:

```
class MyArray( object ):
  def __rmul__( self, other ):
    return MyArray() # value not important for current purpose

from numpy import array
print array([1,2,3]) * MyArray()
```

This yields the following output:

```
[<__main__.MyArray instance at 0x91903ec>
 <__main__.MyArray instance at 0x919038c>
 <__main__.MyArray instance at 0x919042c>]
```

Clearly, rather than calling `MyArray().__rmul__( array([1,2,3]) )` as I had hoped, `__rmul__` is called for every individual element of the array, and the result wrapped in an object array. This seems to me non compliant with python's [coercion rules](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/coercion-rules.html). More importantly, it renders my left multiplication useless.

Does anybody know a way around this?

(I thought a could fix it using `__coerce__` but the linked document explains that that one is no longer invoked in response to binary operators...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that numpy offers a simple fix for this problem. The following code works as intended.

```
class MyArray( object ):
  __array_priority__ = 1. # <- fixes the problem
  def __rmul__( self, other ):
    return MyArray()
```

More information can be found [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.classes.html).